# Losing SSH Connectivity repeatedly on Google Compute Engine

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I ve been coding on vscode remotely connected to an instance on the google Compute Engine. I have an internet connection speed of around 30-40 mbps. What I have observed is I keep losing connection to the remote machine very frequently. What I have also observed is there are times when this issue occurs especially when certain memory intensive operations are run. So,
Question 1: Is there a relationship between RAM and ssh connectivity.
Question 2: Is my internet connectivity speed a problem? If yes what is the minimum amount of speed necessary a seamless coding experience.

Comment: **1.** 30-40 Mbps is more than enough for SSH connectivity which is using for [Remote Development using SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh). **2.** There's no relationship between RAM and SSH connectivity unless your VM instance is overloaded. **3.** Please provide more details about your VM instance (RMA, CPU, machine type) and it's load (CPU and RAM utilization). **4.** Please update your question with [MTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_(software)) from VM instance to your place and in the opposite direction.

Comment: Set "TCPKeepAlive no" in the instance sshg_config - and see if keeps happenning. OpenSSH sends keepalives by default to shutdown unresponsive sessions. If you're behind a corporate firewall or a CGNAT, it can be filtered or rerouted somewhere else.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. I am coding using Remote SSH on VSCode. Even the support guys at google have not been able to sort this. I have used Azure and DigitalOcean before and i have never experienced such an issue. My problem seems to be fixed albeit temporarily when i reboot the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The only relationship between the RAM and the SSH service is that the SSH is also using RAM to be able to operate. In your case, you already got a clue that the SSH Service crashes from time to time and mostly when performing memory intensive operations. Your machine is falling short on resources and hence in order to keep the OS up, the process manager shuts down the processes. SSH is one of those processes. Once you reset the machine, all comes back to normal.
2. With your current speed, connection is not an issue.

One of the best ways to tackle this is:

- increase the resources of your VM (RAM)
- then go back to code and check the requirements and limitation of your app

You can also check this official SSH Troubleshooting guide from google. [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh)